# Homepage not responsive with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, responsive-design

I'm confused! I have made a simple webpage to just show an image and some text. It's responsive and it works fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Internet Explorer 10, but not in Internet Explorer 11.

The problem is that it's not responsive, it take a long time to load and it doesn't show the Font Awesome icons in Internet Explorer 11. What could be the reason for this and how could this be fixed? Really preciate some help since I can't find any solution for this when I google around. Thanks!

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light);

a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #2952a1;
}

html
{
overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
margin:0; 
padding:0; 
height:100%; 
color: #7F7F7F;
height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
margin-top: 2%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

#card {
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 80%;
}

#mobileH1 {
display: none;
}

#desktopH1 {
display: block;
}

#leftSide {
height: auto;
float: left;
width: 50%;
}

#rightSide {
padding-top: 5%;
float: right;
width: 49%;
height: auto;
}

#leftSide img {
display: block;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 1%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
text-align: left;
font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 55px;
margin: 0;
}

p {
font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;
font-size: 28px;
margin: 0;
padding: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 768px)
{

#mobileH1 {
display: block;
}

#desktopH1 {
display: none;
}

#card {
width: 90%;
}

#leftSide {
width: 100%;
}

#rightSide {
float: left;
padding-top: 0;
width: 100%;
}

#leftSide img {
width: 80%;
padding-top: 1%;
}

h1 {
font-size: 36px;
text-align: center;
}

p {
font-size: 24px;
}

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 320px)
{
h1 {
font-size: 28px;
text-align: center;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv"> 
<head>
 <title>Konstkort & affischer</title>
 <meta name="description" content="Description text" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=width-device, initial-scale=1" />
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- css3-mediaqueries.js for IE less than 9 -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
 
</head>
 <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <div id="card">
    <div id="leftSide">
    <h1 id="mobileH1">Headline!</h1>
    <img src="bilder/blomma.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div id="rightSide">
    <h1 id="desktopH1">Headline</h1>
    <p>
    Text
    </p> 
     <p>
    <i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i> Phone number<br>
    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i> Mail
    </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you looking at the site in an actual version of IE11 or is it a simulator? There were some bugs earlier and google, yahoo, bootstrap and many other sites looked strange but that was worked out. Might want to try using the IE edge meta tag just to see if that helps.

Answer (score -2):

It Seems that you have coded proper div tags from your css file and we believe it is not the problem in the code and it might be the reason it get loaded in other browser as well as in Internet Explorer 10. Please try following suggestions to get rid of common issue in "Internet Explorer 11" while it unable to load the webpage.

> You might want to turn off Tracking Protection and ActiveX Filtering
>   in your "Internet Explorer 11" browser (TOOLS option). Tracking Protection and
>   ActiveX Filtering help protect your privacy by blocking images or
>   other content that might put your security or privacy at risk.

If the issue persists please try resetting Internet Explorer's security settings

> Open the desktop, and then tap or click the Internet Explorer icon on
>   the taskbar.Tap or click the Tools button Tools button, and then tap
>   or click Internet options.
>
> On the Security tab, tap or click Default level, and then tap or click
>   OK.

If none of these suggestions work, you can try resetting Internet Explorer to its default settings.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What about the visitor that uses IE11, should they also do all this to be able to view the webpage!?